# Applying for 2 different jobs in same company?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, recruitment, job-offer, human-resources

I have registered with 2 recruiting companies few months before. Now I have been called from both recruiting companies for 2 different vacancies, but same Employer. For 1 vacancy my CV has shortlisted & called next week for the interview. For other still result is pending.

If I have been called for both interviews on same day what I can do? Do I have to inform this to recruiting companies? Or should I remain silent till I receive 2nd vacancy notification?

As I’m so confused with the situation, even I have an answer I’m afraid to take it. Therefore please advise your opinion. This the first time I’m facing this type of situation.

Comment: So you have an interview schedule with one of the vacancies, and for the other vacancy, it's still pending?

Comment: Are the roles similar? Like Dev and Senior Dev or are they completely different Dev/HR?

Comment: It happens; relax. If they're clearly two different vacancies, there's no reason not to interview for both, especially in a larger employer. If you're being called back to talk to the same people, you should let them know so you don't waste their time. Similarly, you should let the recruiters know who you have already interviewed with so they don't waste their own efforts trying to get you back in to talk to the same people. Beyond that... Would you have turned down the second interview if the _same_ recruiter had suggested it? If not, don't turn it down now.

Answer (score 6):

You are going to tell both recruiters that they are targeting the same company on your behalf. Right now, the situation is manageable because the vacancies are different.

I don't think anyone is to blame for this state of affairs. You don't know who the recruiters are targeting because they are not telling you until they arrange the interview. And each of the recruiters has no way of knowing what the other recruiter is up to.

Again, no one is to blame and don't accept any blame. It's just that situations where there will be conflict will pop up occasionally, and they must be managed. If the recruiters call you about the same position, go with the first recruiter to mention that position and tell the other one that you are operating on a first-come, first-served basis, and that you are wishing both well.

Answer (score 2):

It should be obvious to any company where you apply for a job that you will be applying for other jobs as well. And since you are applying for other jobs, it is obvious that you might apply for two jobs at a company that offers more than one job.

If both ask you to come for an interview at the same time - that's the same as applying to two different companies and they ask you for an interview at the same time. It happens. You can't split yourself in two, so you tell the second one that you have an interview at the same time (which is actually good for you, because it shows you are at least competent enough to get two interviews).

Answer (score 2):

If you sign a "right to represent" form with either or both recruiters which reads as follows:

I agree that that I will neither permit nor authorize any other staffing company or individual to submit me as a candidate for **this position**.  *This Right to Represent Agreement pertains to **this assignment only** and does not prevent me from being submitted to other positions by other staffing agencies.*

I understand that this agreement does not guarantee placement and is neither an offer nor a contract of employment.  I further acknowledge that if selected for this contract position, that I will be an employee of Recruiter A.

Then you are operating in a politically, ethically, and professional manner...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to hide the fact that you are using multiple recruiting companies.

When a recruiting company contacts you for a job in a company you already got a reaction, just say that.

```
 I am sorry but I am already in touch with that company.
```

As an additional note, I do not think the employer cares, probably all they care about is whether you are the one they want to hire or not.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't work with more than one recruiter in the same geographic area for the same type of job.  Exactly these types of situations or worse can happen.

Imagine recruiter A sends your resume to Company A for a job.  Not surprisingly, recruiter B sees the same opening and sends your resume to company A for the same job.  Now, if company A is even willing to talk to you after seeing your resume twice from different recruiters (they may not want to deal with the hassle), they won't care who gets paid and likely will pay the first recruiter's agency.  This is not fair to recruiter B who has a reasonable expectation of getting paid for a job they posted you for and you actually got.

In past job searches, I have had recruiters tell me they would not work with me if I was using another recruiter, for exactly this reason.  They don't want to the work unless they know they will get paid.  Seems reasonable.

Comment: This does not work in the UK, as most companies will only work with 1 or 2 recruiters, so unless you use lots of recruiters, you lose out on lots of companies.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find out if the positions are in the same department.  If they are not, then no worries. If they are, you may want to mention this to the recruiter that calls you for the second interview. ("I just wanted to be up front, but I already have an interview scheduled for ***_*** position.  I am not sure if this is with the same manager that you are working with, but I thought I would let you know just in case)  Recruiting companies work on the same (as recruiting competitors) and different (exclusive openings just worked on my one recruiter) all the time.

If you don't get called to interview on the second opening - then there is not any need to disclose.